# how to calculate in sql only the minutes between 2 time slots

Tags: sql-server, datediff, timespan

I have to create a query in SQL Server that calculates the difference in minutes between the time of a start date and the time of an end date considering only the time slots between 8.30 - 13.00 and 15.00 - 19. So, if the date times start and end date include time slots outside the valid range, these minutes must not be included in the calculation.

I use:

```
select datediff(minute, startdate, enddate) as minutes
from table
```

But I can't exclude invalid minutes.

Here are some examples (with datetime values).

```
StardDate: 2022-12-10 00:00:00.000
EndDate: 2022-12-10 09:00:15.000
Duration: 30 minutes.

StartDate: 2022-12-10 10:00:30.000
EndDate: 2022-12-10 16:00:00.000
Duration: 180 (from 10.00 to 13.00) + 60 (from 15.00 to 16.00) minutes.

StartDate: 2022-12-10 00:00:00.000
EndDate: 2022-12-10 08:30:00.000
Duration: 0 minutes.

StartDate: 2022-12-10 00:08:00.000
EndDate: 2022-12-11 03:00:00.000
Duration: 510 minutes.
```

Comment: Some sample data and expected results, in **consumable formats**, will help us help you here.

Comment: Convert your times to #minutes, join to a tally table and count valid rows.

Comment: Are all times always on the same day? So the start and end time will always full on the same date?

Comment: @Larnu, yes, this table stores paid parking stops. So I can leave the car at 8.00 today and pick it up at 3.00 tomorrow.

Comment: So could it be over *many* days? Do you have a Calendar Table?

Comment: @Larnu, not at the moment, should i create it? once created how can I use it in the query where I already extract the parking data including the duration?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Calendar table, one method would be to use that table to create a row for each time slot, and then `JOIN` to that. Then you can use a `CASE` expression to use the appropriate start/end time for the slot, and finally aggregate:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(1,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'20221210 00:00:00'),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'20221210 09:00:15')),
            (2,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'20221210 00:08:00'),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'20221211 03:00:00')))V(SomeID,StartDate,EndDate);
GO

SELECT YT.SomeID,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,V.StartDate, V.EndDAte)) AS TotalMinutes
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,V.StartMinutes, CONVERT(datetime2(0),CT.CalendarDate)) AS StartDate,
                       DATEADD(MINUTE,V.EndMinutes, CONVERT(datetime2(0),CT.CalendarDate)) AS EndDate
                FROM dbo.CalendarTable CT
                     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(510,780),
                                        (900,1140))V(StartMinutes,EndMinutes)) CT ON YT.StartDate <= CT.EndDate
                                                                            AND YT.EndDate >= CT.StartDate
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN YT.StartDate > CT.StartDate THEN YT.StartDate ELSE CT.StartDate END, CASE WHEN YT.EndDate < CT.EndDate THEN YT.EndDate ELSE CT.EndDate END))V(StartDate,EndDate)
GROUP BY YT.SomeID;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```